# is there any solution of the below problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, avconv, pydub

This is code and I'm getting the following issue filename is "ply_audio.py"

```
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    ># read/write data
    > data = AudioSegment.from_file(file="one.wav",format="wav")
    >data.export("new_test.wav")
 > python ply_audio.py

C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't
 find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work

warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't
 find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ply_audio.py", line 4, in <module>
data = AudioSegment.from_file(file="one.wav",format="wav")

File "C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 685, i
n from_file

info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)

 File "C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

File "C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

File "C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using requires ffmpeg (or avconv). I would suggest ffmepg (but you should check the license restrictions of your project if needed).
You could download it from [official](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) then make sure the `bin` folder of the downloaded ffmpeg application is in your path (see https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows for example)
Then your code above will see both ffmpeg and ffprobe binaries.